# openapi generator spring doesn't keep the line breaks from the description in the generated comment

Tags: yaml, swagger, openapi, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I am using openapi generator 5.3.0. with the spring generator.
This is how my enum yaml looks like:

```
type: string
description: |
  ### random text
  
  random text in new line
```

and this is how it look like in the generated enum:

```
/**
 * ### random text  random text in new line
 */
public enum UsageType {
```

I want to keep the line breaks in my comments, any ideas about what should I do?

EDIT: I tried using `<br>` and \n but they don't work

Comment: Sadly no, asking this question was my last resort